# rxjs. is it good practice to have code in subscribe method?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I remember once upon a time I found a recommendation to avoid any code in `subscribe` method and use pipes instead.

```
// suppose bad
observable.subscribe(() => dosmg())

// suppose good
observable
    .pipe(tap(() => dosmg()))
    .subscribe()
```

The reasoning was related to tree shaking. The second option prompted to be better optimizable. Nowadays I can not find this recommendation anymore as well as the opposite recommendation. And lots of learning materials I encountered are adding the code in the `subscribe` method without explanations. Is it still recommended to use pipes instead of the code in `subscribe`?

Comment: Putting code inside `subscribe` is the best way.

Comment: I tend to put code in subscribe if I only have up to 10 lines of code. Anymore than that and it goes in a separate method for readability.

Comment: Seems to me It's better to not put your code inside a subscribe, for better chaining, and reuse of your code.

Comment: No, definitely not. You should think of `subscribe` as "execute this chain now". Business logic should be put in `tap` for example.

Comment: @ritaj your suggestion is basically the opposite of what rxjs represents.

Comment: Don't think so. Can you explain?

Comment: @ritaj The whole point of the observer pattern is to get notified. Not passing anything to `subscribe` makes the stream somewhat pointless. `tap` is meant for things like logging, not for consuming data.

Answer (score 3):

I normally avoid putting logics in subscribe.

The beauty of functional coding is you can combine, zip, merge and extend your observables.

If you put logics in subscribe it just simply lose the portability and harder to refactor at the later stage. Here is a typical stream slicing combining scenario

```
const stream1=observable
    .pipe(tap(() => dosmg()))

const stream1WithLoggin=stream1.pipe(tap(message=>console.log(message))
const stream1WithHttp=stream1.pipe(mergeMap(message=>fetch(someurl))
```

Comment: _"If you put logics in subscribe it just simply lose the portability"_ Why?

Comment: What is return from subscribe is subscription, which can not be extended or piped any more for further usage

Comment: That doesn't explain_"lose portability"_.

Comment: Then why you need operator if you want to put logics in subscribe? operator is to help you operate your logic, no?

Comment: You avoid explaining what you mean by _"lose portability"_. The point of a subscriber is to consume data. The point of tap is executing side effects like logging.

Comment: isn't it very obvious in the example how composition work? or should i also show why put things in subscribe() stops you from composing function further?, In rx point of subscribe is to execute function not neccessary consuming data. Side effect sometime is part of the steam, which can be kept in the stream depends on use case.

Comment: _"should i also show why put things in subscribe() stops you from composing function further?"_ Yes, because subscribing to `observable` does not prevent you from creating any other stream based on it. _"point of subscribe is to execute function"_. `subscribe` creates an observer internally even if you do not pass anything. Data from the stream is **always** consumed by an observer. That's the very point of the observer pattern.

Comment: Please share ur thought as an answer